# gvim doesn't show up in unity apps menu

Tags: unity, gvim

if i enter "vim" in unity search (after pressing Super key") nothing shows up.

I can only start gvim by using Alt+F2 and entering gvim. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have solved the problem for me:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/app-install/desktop/vim-gui-common\:gvim.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

This was suggested by a [related bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-lens-applications/+bug/1062053).

Comment: Does the trick.

Comment: This only worked for me if I escaped the colon: `sudo cp /usr/share/app-install/desktop/vim-gui-common\:gvim.desktop /usr/share/applications/`. I also like the ending slash, just so you know it is a directory.

Answer (score 2):

#### This worked for me:

```
cp /usr/share/app-install/desktop/vim-gui-common\:gvim.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/gvim.desktop
```

#### Explanation:

Copy & rename vim-gui-common:gvim.desktop to gvim.desktop in your user directory, to make it available.

#### Add it to the launcher

Drag ~/.local/share/applications/gvim.desktop to your launcher

The other answer (copy to /usr/share/applications) *didn't* work here in 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at this about a year later, using Ubuntu 16.04.  I wasn't able to find any useful "vim" results in Unity search.  I used Ubuntu Software to install the "gvim" package and it just did everything for me, including putting the shortcut with the correct icon into the Unity toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can install icon using `sudo apt-get install vim-gui-common`. Icon appears after a reboot.